# Applying two CSS styles at once using jQuery

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a webchat system which shows the current 'members' of the chat as a unordered list. A chat member can either be a standard member of the public, a moderator or a police officer. So each list item has a different style:

```
<ul id="MembersList ">
<li class="Police">Mr Policeman</li>
<li class="Moderator">Mr Moderator</li>
<li class="Member">Joe Bloggs 1</li>
<li class="Member">Joe Bloggs 2</li>
<li class="Member">Joe Bloggs 3</li>
</ul>

#MembersList li.Member
{
    list-style-image: url(images/member.png);
}

#MembersList li.Moderator
{
    list-style-image: url(images/member_moderator.png);
}

#MembersList li.Police
{
    list-style-image: url(images/member_police.png);
}
```

That works fine :) Giving each member their own little icon.

Here's where it gets tricky. When a member is typing jQuery adds an additional style to that member, so the list item effectivily changes to this:

```
<li class="Member Typing">Joe Bloggs 3</li>
```

What I now want to achieve is to change the list item icon, but have it show a different icon depending on the member type. So have something like the following CSS:

```
#MembersList li.Member .Typing
{
    list-style-image: url(images/member_typing.png);
}

#MembersList li.Moderator .Typing
{
    list-style-image: url(images/member_moderator_typing.png);
}

#MembersList li.Police .Typing
{
    list-style-image: url(images/member_police_typing.png);
}
```

Except that the above CSS doesn't work.

So please could a CSS guru explain to me the correct CSS to use in this instance? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the space, `.classnameone.classnametwo`:

```
#MembersList li.Member.Typing
{
    list-style-image: url(images/member_typing.png);
}

#MembersList li.Moderator.Typing
{
    list-style-image: url(images/member_moderator_typing.png);
}

#MembersList li.Police.Typing
{
    list-style-image: url(images/member_police_typing.png);
}
```

When you do something like the following, `.classnameone .classnametwo`, you specify an element with the class `.classnametwo` being a child of one with the class `.classnameone`

Comment: No problem. Tough I'm not a sir, makes me feel to be an adult.